# Bluetooth Scanning fails - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Im running a bluetooth scan in background continuously every 2 mins, the problem is sometimes it fails to discover the devices knowing that the devices' bluetooth is on and it's within the range.

Here's the code on scanning:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {

                Log.d("BLDevice", "device found ");
                if (device.getName() != null && (device.getName().toLowerCase().contains("alw") || device.getName().toLowerCase().contains("kontakt"))) {// && device.getName().toLowerCase().contains("alw")) {
                    deviceFound = true;
                    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, Short.MIN_VALUE);
                    String message = timeStamp + " " + device.getName() + ", " + device.getAddress() + ", " + rssi;
                    Log.d("BLDevice", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress() + "\n" + rssi);

                    writeToSDFile(message);
                    stopService();
                }
            }
        }

        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            stopService();
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            if(!deviceFound){
                writeToSDFile(timeStamp + " " + "No Bluetooth Device Found");
                Toast.makeText(context, "No Bluetooth Device Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

and here's the result:

[image]

UPDATE: Added Question

Is there a HIGH SCANNING MODE in Bluetooth Classic? I was thinking maybe the scanning power is not enough sometimes thats why it fails.

Comment: Is it repeatable on different devices? My first thing was about limitation, but I mistake with WiFi.

Comment: I didn't get your point